# How to manually break the cursor within a while loop?

Tags: sql-server, while-loop, database-cursor

If the while loop hits the break command it comes out of the loop and  if cursor hit the break command, how can it break entirely out of the while loop?

For example:

```
DECLARE @CursorTest TABLE 
(
    idcol INT ,
    fld1 INT,
    fld2 INT,
    fld3 CHAR(800)
)

INSERT INTO @CursorTest (fld1, fld2, fld3)

SELECT 1, RAND() * 100 * DATEPART(ms, GETDATE()), LEFT(REPLICATE(CAST(NEWID() AS VARCHAR(36)),30),800)


DECLARE @Variable1 INT, @Variable2 INT
DECLARE CursorName CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
FOR
SELECT idcol    FROM @CursorTest    
OPEN CursorName
FETCH NEXT FROM CursorName  INTO @Variable1
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN   
    if (@Variable1 =10) 
    BEGIN
        BREAK
    END 
    PRINT CAST(@Variable1 AS VARCHAR(5))

FETCH NEXT FROM CursorName  INTO @Variable1
 
END
CLOSE CursorName
DEALLOCATE CursorName
```

Answer (score 35):

You can give some condition in `WHILE` loop that iterates on cursor. First condition would be on `@@FETCH_STATUS` and other would be on which you want to break loop

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 OR @stopLoop = false
   BEGIN
      FETCH NEXT FROM Employee_Cursor;
      //your code
      if condition 
      BEGIN
          @stopLoop = true
      END 
   END;
CLOSE Employee_Cursor;
```

Using BREAK statement

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
   BEGIN
      FETCH NEXT FROM Employee_Cursor;
      //your code
      if condition 
      BEGIN
          BREAK
      END 
   END;
CLOSE Employee_Cursor;
```

Comment: Wouldn't be WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 AND @stopLoop = false instead of an OR ?